# manage.py makemessages doesn't work for project's urls.py file

Tags: django, gettext

I am running `manage.py makemessages --ignore=venv/* -l fr` which seems to be running correctly. Every `gettext()` call is present in the generated `django.po` files except the main `urls.py` file's, therefore showing only the English versions of the URLs.

Other urls.py files' (within apps) `gettext()` calls are successfully found and present in django.po files.

**P.S.:** I am aware of the fact that gettext does not support Python's new f-strings, however there is no f-string inside any `gettext()` call.

My main `urls.py` file looks like this:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path(f'{_("admin")}/', admin.site.urls),
    path(f'{_("narratives")}/', include('notebook.urls', namespace='narrative')),
    prefix_default_language=False,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caused by the way the f-strings work. When I change `path(f'{_("admin")}/', admin.site.urls)` 
 with 
`path('%(link)s/'.format(link=_("admin")), admin.site.urls)` it did work as expected.

I don't know the f-strings in depth, so this is the best workaround I could come up with.